# POST request not allowed exception in lumen framework

Tags: php, http, post, request, lumen

I have started making some routes following the lumen documentation, where it shows basic GET and POST routing.

So I have tried to make some tests in order to understand how they work. While the GET method seems working as expected, the the POST router seems encounter some problems. Here below my test router:

```
$router->post('/foo', function ($req) {
    var_dump($req); die();
});
```

Then I have tried to make a POST request using postman as below:

```
url : http://localhost:8000/foo
raw body of my request: {"key":"thisbodyrequestisdone"}
```

So, I would expect to see the var_dump of my body $req parameter sent via client at http://localhost:8000/foo. But it shows the message:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   [image]

Probably I'm missing something. Can someone tell me exactly how to make a POST request in the right way within lumen? Thanks in advice.

**UPDATE**: below some additional screenshot while trying to use the `$req->all()`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work you should type-hint the `$req` variable, as explained by the docs:

> To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection, you should type-hint the  Illuminate\Http\Request class on your controller constructor or method. The current request instance will automatically be injected by the service container [Source](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests)

So your code should be:

```
$router->post('/foo', function (Request $req) {
    var_dump($req); die();
});
```

Also make sure you import the Request class with `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually if I make a var_dump of the $req object, then the output is very long.. how can I easily access to the body of the POST request?

Comment: You can do that using '$req->all()'

Comment: But with $req->all() I get an empty array while in body payload I have {"key":"thisbodyrequestisdone"} and I would expect it as array.

Comment: Could you update your answer with screenshots and or other relevant information on how exactly you perform the post? I suppose something goes wrong there because it should return an array with all the input variables

Comment: I have added some additional screenshots.

Comment: Could you try the form-encoded and the formdata option instead of raw? Then it will be send as key value combination and it should be visible with all()

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much. But what I cannot understand actually is why with raw body doesn't work. Cause actually is still the same key => value structure... so strange this fact. Do you know why? Anyway thanks!

Comment: Laravel tries to parse it itself, the raw data is not passed as key value combination but as a raw string which you can parse however you like instead of the predefined key value combination. This is also possible with laravel with $req->getContent()

Answer (score -1):

`MethodNotAllowHttpExeptions` -  to fix it:
Create  .htaccess file in your project folder for example "Freelance.local/.htaccess" and just put this code there.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```